# existential elimination

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In the rule of existential elimination

$$\underline{\Delta \vdash \  \exists a \phi (a) \hskip 0.5 cm \Delta, \phi(a) \vdash  \psi}
\\ \Delta \vdash   \psi$$

it is typically said that the variable $a$ should not appear free in the lower sequent. I can certainly see why the variable $a$ appearing free in $\psi$ would cause problems -- then we could have

$$\underline{\exists a \phi (a) \vdash \  \exists a \phi (a) \hskip 0.5 cm \exists a \phi (a), \phi(a) \vdash  \phi(a)}
\\ \exists a \phi (a) \vdash   \phi(a)$$

which is clearly problematic. What I can't quite see is what harm would come from $a$ appearing free in $\Delta$. Is there a problematic instance of this rule in which $a$ appears free in $\Delta$, but not $\psi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\underline{ a=0  \vdash \exists a(a=1)\hskip 0.5 cm a=0, a=1\vdash  0=1}
\\ a=0 \vdash   0=1$$

Comment: Great. Inspired by this, one can construct a 'pure logic' example by letting $\Delta$ be $\{ \exists x Rx , \neg Ra \}$, letting $\phi (a)$ be $R(a)$, and $\phi$ be $\perp$.